# Error "fatal error C1034: windows.h: no include path set"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

OS Windows Vista Ultimate

I am trying to run a program called *minimal.c*. When I type at the command line:

```
C:\Users\nathan\Desktop>cl minimal.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.762 for 80x86

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

minimal.c
minimal.c(5) : fatal error C1034: windows.h: no include path set
```

I have set all the paths:

```
C:\Users\nathan\Desktop>path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin;C:\Windows\system3
;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\AT
.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft S
L Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Bi
n\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.
.0_13\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Co
mon Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (March
009)\Include;C:\Users\nathan\Desktop\glut-3.7.6-bin\glut-3.7.6-bin;C:\Program F
les (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
 Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\Include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\Include\gl
```

I have gone and made sure *windows.h* is in the directory. I'm setting the path too. It's
in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\Include`.

I have Visual Studio 2005.

I have exhausted all possibilities. Any ideas?

Answer (score 61):

You could also run the *vcvars32.bat* file from the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin` (this is in your path) prior to your `cl` command.

Like this:

```
C:\Users\nathan\Desktop>vcvars32
C:\Users\nathan\Desktop>cl minimal.c
```

*vcvars32* calls `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat` which sets up the required environment for compiling and linking.

The environment variables are `INCLUDE`, `LIB`, and `PATH`.

The compiler looks for header files in the INCLUDE path during compile, and libraries are fetched from the LIB path during link.

Comment: i ran vcvars32 as you said and the windows.h is not a problem anymore. i dont understand that if i have the path in environment variables why it didnt work unless i run that. Do i have to run that everytime i open a commandline prior to compiling...it also wants to know where Gl.h is which is included in my path as well but its not finding it.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK\Include\gl

Comment: As a side note: there is also **64 bit** variant of this file: _vcvars64.bat_.

Answer (score 17):

For me, with Visual Studio 2017,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd.bat"
```

is the command to use before compiling with `cl`.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-the-visual-studio-command-line) is the documentation.

Answer (score 9):

In your project folder, open a PowerShell window and run:

```
cmd /c 'call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat" && cl minimal.c '
```

Comment: Why do you have to write that in one line with the call command? This is the only solution that worked for me...

Answer (score 6):

When you started the command line, did you run the included command line shortcut that comes with the Visual Studio setup? This will set the correct environment variables for you so that the compilation will work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You've added your INCLUDE paths to your PATH environment variable.  Use vcvars32.bat as the others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Your path variable might be too long. Windows can’t take more than 1023 characters in the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue getting the

```
fatal error C1034: stdio.h: no include path set
```

and after running the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvars64.bat` cmd/batch script would get the

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
```

error message. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54653035/4999991), and other posts on that page, I suspected that the `Windows 10 SDK` package must be installed. After installation and running the `vcvars64.bat` script from the path mentioned above, the problem was solved.

**P.S.** As explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc), an alternative to manually finding and running the above cmd/batch script, you may just do <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and search for `Developer Command Prompt for ...`, in my case it is `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have version 2017 of the compiler cl.exe (you installed Visual Studio 2017), in the command prompt you need go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build" and run 'vcvars32.bat' for x86 compilation or vcvars64.bat for x64 compilation.